# как отключить скрипт при уменьшении ширины браузера без перезагрузки старницы

Tags: jquery, браузер

Есть такой код. Как при уменьшении браузера отключить этот скрипт Только без перезагрузки браузера сейчас отключается только с перезагрузкой

```
$(document).ready(function()  { 
 $(window).resize(function() { 
  if($(window).width() < 960) { 
    $('.mobile-nav').waSlideMenu({
                backLinkContent: 'Назад',
                backOnTop: true,
                setTitle: true,
                loadContainer: '#content',
                slideSpeed: 100
            });


  }   
  else { 

  } 
 }).resize(); 


});
```

Comment: всмысле отключается с перезагрузкой? насколько я понял вам нужно чтобы срабатывал только при увеличении окна браузера, тогда вам нужно ввести переменную в которой хранить предыдущую ширину браузера.

Comment: Если опираться на документацию, то в else надо прописать `$('.mobile-nav').waSlideMenu('exec','destroy');`

Comment: Если добавить этот код то не отключатся совсем

Comment: может есть какое то другое решение?! как при медиа запросах. Мне нужно простоотключить скрипт при разных расширениях